# Laravel 5.2 validation errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-5

I have some trouble with validation in Laravel 5.2
When i try validate request in controller like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
                'title' => 'required',
                'content.*.rate' => 'required',
            ]);
```

Validator catch error, but don't store them to session, so when i'm try to call in template this code

```
 @if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Laravel throw the error

```
Undefined variable: errors (View: /home/vagrant/Code/os.dev/resources/views/semantic/index.blade.php)
```

When i'm try validate with this code

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required',
                'content.*.rate' => 'required'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput($request->all())
                    ->withErrors($validator, 'error');
            }
```

Variable $error also not available in template but if i try to display errors in controller

```
   if ($validator->fails()) {
                dd($validator->errors()->all());
            }
```

Errors displays but i can't access to them from template.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try "->withErrors($validator, 'error');" without the 'error' so:
->withErrors($validator);

Comment: in v5.2 you only put Route in to :  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});

Answer (score 50):

**Update as of Laravel 5.2.27**

Laravel now supports the web middleware by default as you can see here: [source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L56)

In other words, you no longer need to wrap your routes around the web middleware group because it does it for you in the RouteServiceProvider file. However, if you are using a version of Laravel between 5.2.0 and 5.2.26, then refer to the method below:

**Below only applies to Laravel 5.2.0 to 5.2.26**

Without seeing your `routes.php` or `Kernel.php` file, here is what I suspect is happening.

The way middlewares work has changed from 5.2 and 5.1. In 5.1, you will see this in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];
```

This array is your application's global HTTP middleware stack. In other words, they run on **every** request. Take a note at this particular middleware: `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`. This is what adds the `$errors` variable on every request.

However, in 5.2, things have changed to allow for both a web UI and an API within the same application. Now, you will see this in that same file:

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

The global middleware stack now only checks for maintenance. You now have a middleware group called "web" that includes a bulk of the previous global middleware. Remember that it is like this to allow for both a web UI and an API within the same application.

So how do we get that `$errors` variable back?

In your routes file, you need to add your routes within the "web" middleware group for you to have access to that `$errors` variable on every request. Like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});
```

If you aren't going to build an API, another option is to move the "web" middlewares to the global middleware stack like in 5.1.

Comment: Indeed, this works! I totally forgot about `web` middleware!

Comment: Just as a heads up, if your routes are automatically cached you will need to run `php artisan route:clear` upon this change.

Comment: @Dmitry please check this answer as the correct one if it solved your problem, it helps others who come here looking for a solution to the same problem!

Comment: thanks, that's a better explanation than anything in the documentation. I think the Laravel guys try to be too smart for their own good. I've found 5.2 to be a real pain to understand via the docs.

Comment: By this, do you mean move all functions (including headers and body) into this function?

Comment: @cid, Answering my own question above, yeah, copy them exactly... see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: or add `public function __construct(){ $this->middleware('web'); }` to controller

Comment: @Ken That will actually not work because "terminatable" middlewares are not supported in the controller. However, there has been a recent change so that web middlewares are supported by default, which I will update in my answer.

Comment: Far better explanation than Laravel guys on their website >:( @ThomasKim

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
return redirect()->back()
              ->withInput($request->all())
              ->withErrors($validator->errors()); // will return only the errors
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace:

```
->withErrors($validator, 'error');
```

with:

```
->withErrors($validator);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Replace

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});

// with 

Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you add a description as to why the latter works and what does `middleware` vs `middlewareGroups`. Thanks!

Comment: I don’t know exactly (I’m new in PHP and Laravel too) but if you take a look in app\Http\Kernel.php the “web” is defined in $middlewareGroups array.
I follow a Laravel tutorial and there is used with “middleware” but in my case it function with “middlewareGroups”.    :o)

Comment: This works!  The clue (I think) is the naming of the protected variables in the app/Http/Kernel.  The given by Thomas Kim contains this, but it wasn't clear until I saw this simple snippet.  Thanks!  This took me _hours_ to fix!

Answer (score 1):

I have my working validation code in laravel 5.2 like this

first of all create a function in model like this

### In model add this line of code at starting

### use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

```
public static function validate($input) {

            $rules = array(
                'title' => 'required',
                'content.*.rate' => 'required',
              );
            return Validator::make($input, $rules);
        }
```

and in controller call this function to validate the input

### use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

```
  $validate = ModelName::validate($inputs);
    if ($validate->passes()) {
          ///some code
     }else{
           return Redirect::to('Route/URL')
                            ->withErrors($validate)
                            ->withInput();
      }
```

Now here comes the template part

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

### and Above all the things you must write your Route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::resource('RouteURL', 'ControllerName');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you Routes in **`web`** middleware like below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});
```

and In `app\Http\Kernel.php` move `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` from the `web` `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});
```

as well as this also works

```
Route::post('location',array(
    'as'=>'location',
    'middlewareGroups'=>'web',
    'uses'=>'myController@function'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Controller
$this->validateWith([
    'title' => 'required',
    'content.*.rate' => 'required',
]);


// Blade Template
@if ($errors->has('title'))
    <span class="error">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
@if ($errors->has('anotherfied'))
    <span class="error">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('anotherfied') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Find the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html).

Answer (score 0):

Route

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
    Route::resource('/post', 'PostController');
});
```

Functions

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request, [
       //input field names
      'title' => 'required|max:20',
      'body' => 'required',
   ]);
}
```

View

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
@endif
```