# Undefined variable: errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-middleware, laravel-5

When I want to register a user in my laravel project, the page always says

> Undefined variable: errors (View: /var/www/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php)"

According to the Laravel documentation, `$errors` should always automatically be set:

> So, it is important to note that an $errors variable will always be available in all of your views on every request, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used.

I have this on on every view when I use:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

or any other way when I want to use the `$errors` variable.

Why is this? I never had this problem before.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What version of Laravel? Specifically, in your `composer.lock` file, what version is it pulling?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't messed with 5.2 yet, but I can clearly see in the documentation what you are saying. Might be a bug in 5.2? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Comment: Yes, Laravel 5.2 has bug. Many people have this same problem with Laravel 5.2

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420590/laravel-5-2-validation-errors?rq=1

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71614936/14344959

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You should make sure that in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `middlewareGroups` property for `web` you have:

```
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

in this array. Compare this with https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

**EDIT**

It seems you need to add `'middleware' => 'web'` for route you are using or put `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` into `$middleware` property array

## **or**

Inside of the routes.php file try to create your routes within the following block

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //routes here
});
```

**UPDATE FOR NEWER VERSIONS OF LARAVEL APPLICATION**

Be aware that you might run into problems also in case you use `web` middleware twice. There was a change in Laravel application **5.2.27** (don't confuse it with Laravel framework you use at the moment - you might use Laravel framework for example 5.2.31 but have Laravel application in version 5.2.24) in which `web` middleware is applied automatically for all routes. So in case of problems, you should open your `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file and verify its content.

You can compare it also here :

- [RouteServiceProvider for Laravel application  5.2.24](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.24/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)
- [RouteServiceProvider for Laravel application  5.2.27](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)

In case you have newer version (that applies `web` middleware automatically), you shouldn't use `web` middleware in `routes.php` anymore or you should modify your `RouteServiceProvider` method to not apply `web` group middleware. Otherwise if `web` middleware group is automatically applied in this provider and you use it also in `routes.php` you might get very unexpected results.

Comment: It's already in there...
Copy-pasted the whole block to be sure, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you updated app from older Laravel release or you start new app from scratch in Laravel 5.2 ?

Comment: Started from scratch via scotchbox

Comment: Can you explain the first option a little bit more? Or where I should do this? 

I used your second option ('\illuminatte\...::class', into '$middleware') This solves the error, but now it gives me a new error: >Session store not set on request.

Or what should I do to fix this one?

Already thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anhinga Ok, so you should put also in `$middleware` also others from `web` group - `EncryptCookies , AddQueuedCookiesToResponse , StartSession and VerifyCsrfToken` (in same notation as in file Kernel I put link). At the moment you don't have session started so you are getting this error

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks!

Now the problem is that I can only make 1 DB call... 
I have to restart my sotchbox every time I make a call.. I can only check the phpmyadmin page when I restart scotchbox, and can only log in or register 1 user. After that, laravel doesn't find the DB anymore. (Also php my admin gives a 404 error after 1 call that)

Answer (score 20):

I had this very same issue with Laravel 5.2.x.

Inside of the `routes.php` file try yo create your routes within the

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //routes here
}
```

statement.

Comment: Yeah that was the same issue with me too. I had created the home(`/`) route outside the `web` middleware

Answer (score 5):

Also to be aware of: If you write tests and your view **has** $errors variable make sure you don't use **WithoutMiddleware** trait.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and solved this one by adding routes into middleware property array as well,

**BUT**

it worked only after calling `php artisan route:cache` (clearing route cache) subsequently.

I hope some of you would find this useful.

Comment: What? Cache needs to be cleared, in order middleware to working well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing this error too and later realised I had used the `WithoutMiddleware` trait as a means to bypass authentication for this particular test, but it ended up removing the validation error binding too. So I had to stop using the trait to keep the views working.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem, too.
Did you find a solution for testing stuff which has both the error variable and needs the `WithoutMiddleware` aswell?

Comment: @Fanmade Unfortunately I didn't. In my tests I just created a user and logged them in for each test. Fortunately laravel makes this possible with very little code so I don't mind it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **App\Http\Kernel.php** file. Move all the things of `$middlewareGroups` properties to `$middleware`.

Check for more details-
http://www.tisuchi.com/laravel-5-2-undefined-variable-error-validation/

Answer (score 2):

count is not really realiable since it assumes the variable already exists. change the condition check to: `@if($errors->has())` or just `@if($errors)`

Also if you are redirecting make sure to use this in your controller

```
return redirect()->back()->with('errors', $validator->messages());
```

EDIT: seen now that you are using L5.2
This may answer your question - you need to put your Routes in Route group.

[Laravel 5.2 validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420590/laravel-5-2-validation-errors)

Comment: No, it checks for existance
EDIT: if you are speaking of my controller suggestion, that part is only if for example - validation fails.

Comment: not really... where does it check for existance? $errors->has() ? assumes that $errors variables exists

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, has() method is boolean, so it will return 0 or 1 just like if you do if($errors)

Comment: To be more clear. Count needs to check inside of a variable $errors to find out how many items are there in array. has() method only return true or false without checking the variable. Hence, thats why it is method. I'm using my error handling in laravel like this since L4 and it works without a single problem aswell on my L5.1

Comment: I think you misanderstand something... $errors->has() means that a function called $has() is called on $errors. If $errors does not exists ( or is null or does not define has() function ) this will fail. Try it with $notexistant->has(). that will fail.

Comment: Laravel always has $errors. The question is is it an array or empty var.

Comment: Nevermind - saw now that question was about L5.2 - it is middleware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will be fixed by using this method.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
        //routes should go here
});
```

If this doesn't help you, just run the following artisan command in addition to the above code:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

I solved in this way while using 5.2.*

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $middleware = [              \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Social\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Social\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [

    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
```

make your kernel look like this