# not fixable undefined variable errors laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I keep having this error every time I try to validate a form:

> Undefined variable: errors (View: /home/vagrant/Code/talents/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

I tried modifying the `kernel.php` file, and also adding the route into the `'middleware' => 'web'` in the routes file, but none of those seem to fix the problem.

[Undefined variable: errors in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel)

Comment: Do you have cached routes in `bootstrap/routes.php` ?

Comment: Show us the relevant files such as kerel.php!

Comment: it is all working, in regards to the errors. the problem is the redirect function. It is not passing to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to session errors you need sessions. You should move your '/' route to the 'web' middleware group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });        
});
```

The 'web' middleware group gives you sessions and the session errors.

If you have this setup at the moment and are still having that issue, you may want to change any adjustments you made to Kernel.php and use the default one. If you change the middleware applied to the 'web' group, you could cause an issue where things dont get applied correctly.

In regard to the session errors, those are being shared with views in `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`, which the 'web' middleware group has applied.

Comment: It seems OP mentioned this solution doesn't work for him

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was not the errors. It was a problem when passing the data back the data to the views return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);

Comment: That is odd, considering there is always $errors available to the views when the 'web' group is applied. If there isn't $errors in the session it adds an empty ViewErrorBag.

Comment: the problem wasn't the errors. I have a problem with the function redirect(). when I use that function, it goes to the url but no data is being passed. i.e.: return redirect()->back ()->withErrors ($validator);  it goes back to the url but no $validator nor Errors is being passed.

Comment: is the route where you are flashing those errors, in the 'web' group as well ?

Comment: this is what I have: Route::post ('auth/register', ['as'=> 'postRegister', 'uses'=> 'AuthController@postRegister', 'middleware'=>['web']]);  Route::get ('auth/register', ['as'=> 'register', 'uses'=> 'AuthController@getRegister', 'middleware'=>['web']]); and in my controller I check if the validator fails the this code runs return redirect ()->back ()->withErrors ($validator ); and in the view @if ($errors)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

You may change any one of the following:

**1. put your working route `(app/http/routes.php)` on**

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Here like
    Route::get('/', 'TodoController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'TodoController@store');
});`

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smm38.png)

**2. Move your `protected $middlewareGroups web` `(app/Http/Kernel.php)` on `protected $middleware = []`**

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1P0C.png)