# Undefined variable: errors in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get this error exception in Laravel 5.2. I am trying to access auth/login

> - Undefined variable: errors
> - Undefined variable: errors (View:
>     C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\laravel\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

This is my routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });


    Route::get('about' , 'PagesController@about');

    Route::resource('articles' , 'ArticlesController');

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
    ]);

});
```

This is auth/login.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/email') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: show the `login` code? and on which line you think problem arises

Comment: @Elliot, chow code in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\laravel\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php

Comment: your question is similar as this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel) so i thing you find solution from here.

Comment: check your Login Controller & pass $error variable to View. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected $middleware = [ 

           \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,          
           \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class, 

   ];
```