# Form issue in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In the routes.php

```
Route::get('/form1', 'FriendsController@getAddFriend');
Route::post('/form1', 'FriendsController@postAddFriend');
```

In the app/Http/Controllers/FriendsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\FriendFormRequest; 
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Response;
use View;

class FriendsController extends Controller
{
public function getAddFriend()
{
    return view('friends.add');
}

public function postAddFriend(FriendFormRequest $request)
{
    return Response::make('Friend added!');
}
}
```

In the app/Http/Requests/FriendFormRequest.php

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Response;

class FriendFormRequest extends Request
{
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'email_address' => 'required|email'
    ];
 }

public function authorize()
{
            return true;
}


public function forbiddenResponse()
{

    return Response::make('Permission denied foo!', 403);
}


public function response()
{

}
}
```

In the resources/views/friends/add.blade.php

```
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p class="error">{{ $error }}</p>
 @endforeach

<form method="post">
    <label>First name</label><input name="first_name"><br>
    <label>Email address</label><input name="email_address"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

when i run by http://localhost/laravel/public/form1

I am getting error as "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

When I remove the following line

```
 @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p class="error">{{ $error }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

It displays the form

What is the error?

Comment: Please post the stack trace (under the "whoops").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can think of is that your $errors variable is not existing and that's what causes the script to throw an exception.

**1.** If you are using Laravel 5.2 you might find your answer here: 
[Undefined variable: errors in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel)

Basically in in *app/Http/Kernel.php* you need to check if *$middlewareGroups['web']* contains

```
  \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

**2.** If you are using another Laravel version, probably you can add an additional check like this:

```
     @if(isset($errors))
       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
         <p class="error">{{ $error }}</p>
       @endforeach
     @endif
```

---

To further investigate the problem you need to give us the stack trace of the exception. If you only see the **"Whoops ..."** message, then go in you **.env** file and change ***APP_DEBUG = true***