# Why error messages doesn't Appear in Laravel views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to pass custom validation messages to my view using a custom request when storing a role.

I have create a new Request called `StoreRoleRequest`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class StoreRoleRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'   => 'required'
        ];
    }

    protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'the name of the Role is mandatory',
        ];
    }
}
```

And then pass this custom Request to my store function in the `RoleController` like this:

```
public function store(StoreRoleRequest $request)
{
    Role::create($request->all());
    return redirect(route('role.index'));
}
```

I have a view that show the create role form where the validation seems to work properly but without showing me error even if i call them into the view like this:

```
{!! Former::open()->action(route('role.store')) !!}
@if (count($errors->all()))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
{!! Former::text('name')->label('Groupe name')   !!}
{!! Former::text('display_name')->label('Displayed name')   !!}
{!! Former::text('description')->label('Description')   !!}

{!! Former::actions( Button::primary('Save')->submit(),
                    Button::warning('Clear')->reset()  ,
                    Button::danger('Close')->asLinkTo('#')->withAttributes(['data-dismiss' => 'modal'])
 )!!}
{!! Former::close() !!}
```

Has anyone an idea why the errors doesn't appear into the view ? am I looping something inside the custom Request ?

**EDIT**

NB: Even in the login and the registration form the errors doesn't appear anymore.

In this case i have change my middlware that was pointed to web `['middleware' => ['web']` to this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => []], function () 
{
    // other routes
    Route::resource('role', 'RoleController');
});
```

and all my errors displayed perfectly.

have you locate the root cause about this issue ?

Comment: There might be many reasons. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel/34454302#34454302 - it might help

Comment: First of all dump: `{{ dd($error) }}`. I think that this is inner collection and thats why it dosen't showing nothing at all.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: the middlware is correctly inserted as exactly the answer you submit.

Comment: @FilipKoblański: when there are errors it will not enter to the method inside the controller, it will be blocked before.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek: can you please comment on my EDIT session ? :)

Comment: @Drwhite I've just answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your question update it seems, you have newer version of Laravel application (don't confuse it with Laravel framework). 
To verify this, open file `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` and verify method what's the content of `map` method. In case it launches `mapWebRoutes` it means that you have `5.2.27+` application which applies `web` group middleware automatically.

In case `web` middleware is applied automatically you **shouldn't** apply `web` middleware in your `routes.php` file because it will cause unexpected behaviour.

So you should either remove `web` middleware from your `routes.php` in case you have `mapWebRoutes` defined in your `RouteServiceProvider` class or you can modify your `RouteServiceProvider` class to not apply `web` group middleware automatically. It's up to you which solution you choose.

Just for quick reference:

- [RouteServiceProvider for Laravel application  5.2.24](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.24/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)
- [RouteServiceProvider for Laravel application  5.2.27](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask if errors exists by this way:

```
@if($errors->any())
    // Your code
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    // More code
@endif
```

Also remove the `formatErrors` function from the request... You don't need it...

The function `messages()` is responsible for returning your custom messages...

Regards.

Comment: Doesn't work it seems that the problem is not on displaying the errors but i think is something related to session !

Comment: Is this the only view you are having problem with the error mesaages?

Comment: I have just begin with server side validation and this is the first one.

Comment: Try to change your `store` function's header from this `public function store(StoreRoleRequest $request)` to this `public function store(Request $request)`, and then add `dd($request->all())` in the function (before of return statement) and see what your controller is receiving...

Comment: i used to work with Request and it recieve all inputs() from the view after submiting the form but the issue is about validation it work properly but just problem of displaying the errors !

Comment: Try to comment the `messages()` function... Laravel should send the predefined messages...