# Laravel : @foreach Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

i have error but in foreach :**Undefined variable: infos**
that's my View :

```
@foreach ($infos as $info)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $info->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->phone2 }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

and my controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $info = Info::latest()->get();
        return view('info.admin')->with('infos', $info);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined variable: errors in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel)

Comment: My problem was in Routing name dosen't exists !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass parameters to the view like this:

```
   return view('info.admin', ['infos' => $infos]);
```

What you've been doing before using `with` has a different effect, it flashes the data to the session. [Check out this doc here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following code gives you the "There are no infos".
If it does, that means that the $infos variable in the controller is not returning data, and thus giving you the error

```
@if(empty($infos))
    <tr><td>There are no infos</td></tr>
@else
   @foreach ($infos as $info)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $info->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $info->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $info->code }}</td>
            <td>{{ $info->phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ $info->phone2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forelse will be better:

```
@forelse($infos as $key => $info)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $info->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $info->phone2 }}</td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr>
        <td>Data Not Found</td>
    </tr>
@endforelse
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $info = Info::latest()->get();
    return view('info.admin')->with(['infos'=> $info]);
}
```