# Laravel 5.8 Password Reset undefined variable $errors

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I'm having trouble resetting my password. The Forget password is working good and I'm getting the email however when I click on the `Reset Link` button I get redirected to the password reset page and throws an error: **undefined variable $errors**.

Password reset is managed by Laravel doesn't it? If so then why I'm getting this

**Code:**

**`ForgetPasswordController.php`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class ForgetPasswordController extends BaseController
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError($validator->errors()->first());
        }

        // We will send the password reset link to this user.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        if (Password::RESET_LINK_SENT == $response) {
            return $this->sendResponse('A password reset message was sent to your email address');
        }

        return $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors();
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $errors = $this->parseErrors(['email' => trans($response)])->first();

        return $this->sendError($errors);
    }

    protected function parseErrors($provider)
    {
        if ($provider instanceof MessageProvider) {
            return $provider->getMessageBag();
        }

        return new MessageBag((array) $provider);
    }
}
```

**`\views\auth\passwords\reset.blade.php`**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined variable: errors in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454081/undefined-variable-errors-in-laravel)

Comment: @Gulshan Not working man

Comment: provide `reset.blade.php` source code. As per error there is problem on that view page

Comment: @Gulshan added please check it

Comment: instead of showing an error with input try show common error with `@if (isset($errors) && $errors->any())
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-alt">
                <strong><i class="fa fa-bug fa-fw"></i> Ошибка</strong><br>
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
@endif`

Comment: also try `if($validator->fails()) { return redirect()->back() ->withErrors($validator)->withInput(); }` instead of  `if ($validator->fails()) { return $validator->errors(); }`