# Undefined variable: $errors in custom Laravel package

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to develop  a local Laravel  package  where I can put all my blade components and views so I can include my repo in all my future applications.
At this point, All things is ok except one problem:  "Undefined variable $errors"
in my blade. I'm using @error directive. I know the problem occurred in this section of my code
but my question is why not included variable $error within the blade view of my package?

Routes:

```
use Adway\Hauth\Http\Controllers\HauthController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/login',[HauthController::class,'login'])->name('login');
Route::get('/logout',[HauthController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::get('/register',[HauthController::class,'register'])->name('register');
Route::post('auth/login',[HauthController::class,'loginAutenticate'])->name('hauth.login');
Route::post('auth/register',[HauthController::class,'registerAutenticate'])->name('hauth.register');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/dashboard',[HauthController::class,'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');

});
```

View:

```
<x-app>

    <div class="p-5 border-2 border-green-500 ">
        <form action="{{ route('hauth.login') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
           <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-8 gap-y-4">


               <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
                   <label for="name">email:</label>
                   <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required>
                   @error('email')
                            <span class="bg-red-400">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror

                </div>

                <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
                    <label for="name">password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
                            @error('password')
                            <span class="bg-red-400">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="px-2 bg-green-400 max-w-min rounded-md">login</button>

           </div>
        </form>


    </div>
</x-app>
```

service provider:

```
 public function boot(): void
    {
        // $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/lang', 'adway');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'hauth');
        // $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');

        // Publishing is only necessary when using the CLI.
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->bootForConsole();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no `HauthController` and this template does not use `{{ $errors }}`.

Answer (score 1):

I has same issue. I can't get validation message any kind of method. I tried **Request class**, Then in controller **$request->validate([]) method**, even I tried **Validator::make() Class function** but I has same issue to get validation message.

but finally I got solution about this. actually Laravel puts validation messages in session.

& then `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`  class bind that errors to views using **errors named variable**

& then when we can get validation errors messages using `$errors->all()`

when we set route in default application's **route/web.php** this process Laravel perform automatically because Out of the box, the web and api middleware groups are automatically applied to your application's corresponding routes/web.php and routes/api.php files by the **App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider**. [see this Laravel doc page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-groups)

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

---

**-: Solution :-**

we need to pass **web** named middleware group to our route as like below. then `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` will automatically appending Validation messages to views automatically.

```
Route::middleware('web')->get('test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

or we can create route group & pass middleware to that route group as like below

```
Route::middleware('web')->group(function(){
    // Route::get('test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
    //... define your routes here
});
```

I hope this one helps to you.