# What is the reason: Undefined variable in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello I am new to Laravel and working on my first project using Laravel 5. I am getting this error when i pass the data from controller to view. I am stuck last three days. I have checked all questions from online blogs, even stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution please help. Here is my code:

```
App\Routes\web.php    
Route::get('/list', 'CustomerController@list');    
App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController.php

public function list(){
    $first = 'Mian';
    $last = 'Amir';
    $fullName = $first . " " . $last;
    //dd($fullName);
    return view('new')->with("fullName", $fullName);
    //return view('new')->withFullName($fullName);
}

Resources\Views\new.blade.php

@extends('master')    
@section('content')

<h1>New Content Will Goes Here: {{$fullName}}</h1>    

@endsection
```

I have also tried these also:

```
//return view('new')->with('customer', $customers);
//return View::make('new')->with(array('customers' => $customers));
// return View::make('new', compact('customers'));
/$customers = DB::table('customers')->get();

//return view('new', ['customers' => $customers]);
//return View::make('new', compact('customers'));
//return View::make('new')->with('customers', $customers);
//dd($customers);
//return View::make('new')->with(array('customers' => , $customers));

//$customers = Customer::all();
//dd($customers);
//return View::make('view')->with('customers', $customers);
//return View::make('view', compact('customers'));
//return $view->with('customers', $customers)->with('q', $q);
//return view('view', ['key' => 'The big brown fox jumped over the lazdog']);
//$key = 'If a would chuck can chuck wood,';
//return view('view', compact('key'));
```

This is the error page:

[image: This is error page please check it]

Comment: From your question I cannot the see error you are etting. Please expand your question with the error message.

Comment: In the code you posted, are those different files you just posted together, or is your controller and view in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

pass it as

```
return View('new')->with(['fullName' => $fullName]);
```

Comment: `::with()` method is intended to get a key value pair as separate parameters. It's more like `return view('new', ['fullName' => $fullName]);` but it doesn't change a thing comparing to Amir's example code.

Comment: @PaulKertscher , i have attached image please check it.

Comment: I have used,  return view('new')->with(["fullName" => $fullName]); but same error Undefined variable fullName:

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.6, this is my laravel application version which i have checked from , php artisan --version command. Can anyone tell me, should i changed the Kernel.php file because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474224/undefined-variable-errors-laravel-5-2 , here is telling that this is problem in version of laravel

Comment: Can anyone help me in this error because i have tried all options from online resources but no solution, i am sucked

Comment: dd value for fullname in controller do you get it as needed?

Comment: even the code works at my end if a pass the data the way u passed for the same

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping, i have add into \Routes\Web.php this code and everything is working good, Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/list', 'CustomerController@list');
});

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a variable into view in multiple way

```
    public function list(){
        $first = 'Mian';
        $last = 'Amir';
        $fullName = $first . " " . $last;

        return view('new')->with(["fullName"=>$fullName]);  //Or
        return view('new', ["fullName"=>$fullName]);     //Or
        return view('new', compact("fullName"));       //Or

        Session::put('fullName', $fullName); 
        return view('new');  //then in view- Session::get('fullName');

        //Or using dynamic method which I personally dislike without any reason! :P
        return view('new')->withFullName($fullName); 
       //But i this case in view you have to use underscored variable $full_name !!!

    }
```

Hope these will help newbies .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple and flexible possibilities in laravel

```
 return view('new')->withFullName($fullName);
```

**OR**

```
return view('new')->with('fullName' , $fullName);
```

**OR**

```
    return view('new',compact ('fullName'))
```

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views)

Comment: thanks for multiple , interesting options for variable passing to view from controller.