# ErrorException when using $errors in view in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my view

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

I expect $errors to be available to my view, so I  want to display them

However, this block throws the following exception :

> ErrorException in 958ab466b0f563093a9e18c3ff070466cc69459a.php line
>   38: Undefined variable: errors (View: .....filename.blade.php

Comment: Are you sure that the variable $errors is available in the view every time other than in erroneous occasions? I think you should check whether the errors variable is set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Laravel 5.2, make sure to put your routes within the `web` middleware group like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Add your routes here
});
```

I wrote a more in-depth explanation on why this is the case here: [Laravel 5.2 validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420590/laravel-5-2-validation-errors/34421349#34421349)

In a nutshell, Laravel 5.0 and 5.1 used to run several middlewares automatically. One of these middlewares (`\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession`) used to inject the `$errors` variable automatically into all your views. Laravel 5.2 makes this all optional now, but you can achieve the same effect by simply putting your routes within the `web` middleware group.

Comment: The [Laravel Docs for Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors), have been updated to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks Thomas and lagbox. This fixed it for me.