# Custom request not calling controller method on form validation success

Tags: validation, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use a custom request on Laravel 5 to validate inputs sent through post, but when the form fields are ok, ie. form validation goes fine, my controller's method is not called. Is that a bug? What's wrong? I know it's possible 'cause I did this once ago in another project. I was using version 5.2.6 in this project, then I thought It was a issue with this specific version, that's when I "switched back" to 5.1 but editing my `composer.json`, deleting `vendor` folder and then reinstalling with `composer install`.

Contents of my UserController:

```
//...
public function save(Requests\CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->username = $request->input('username');
    $user->password = $request->input('password_confirmation');
    //$user->profile_id = $request->input('profile');
    $user->profile_id = 1;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('get_user_read');
}
//...
```

CreateUserRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'profile' => 'required',
        'name'    => 'required',
        'username'   => 'required|unique:users,username',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_confirmation'   => 'required|same:password',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'profile.required' => 'O campo perfil é obrigatório!',
        'name.required' => 'O campo nome é obrigatório!',
        'username.required' => 'O campo nome de usuário é obrigatório!',
        'username.unique' => 'O nome de usuário já foi registrado!',
        'email.required' => 'O campo email é obrigatório!',
        'email.unique' => 'O email informado já foi registrado!',
        'email.email' => 'O email informado não é válido!',
        'password.required' => 'O campo senha é obrigatório!',
        'password_confirmation.required' => 'O campo de confirmação de senha é obrigatório!',
        'password_confirmation.same' => 'A confirmação de senha não confere com a senha informada!',
    ];
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if " Requests\CreateUserRequest " is the real path to your request file

Comment: So if you dd()  your request in the save function nothing happens?

Comment: To test if my save function is ever called i put ```return " ";``` before everything else; and it's never executed. I should see a blank page. As I said above, when I use my custom request to validade form inputs, my save function is NEVER called.

Comment: Does your form has all these values described in array of `rules` method? I.e. profile, name, username, email, password, password_confirmation. Check if it works when you change your `rules` method with `return []`

Comment: Did answered correctly for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.2 there is some feature called [Middleware Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups).

It seems it gets you redirected back to your form because of FAILED validation without showing any errors. You would not see any errors until you enable sharing them within a session.

To make errors visible please ensure that `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` Middleware is enabled. By default it's included to "web" middleware group.

To solve your issue you can simply create a route group and set a middleware group to "web" like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Here comes your routes
});
```

Please take a look on this: [Laravel 5.2 validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420590/laravel-5-2-validation-errors)

Also ensure you have a blade error tags in your form like this:

```
{!! Form::text('profile') !!}
@if ($errors->has('profile'))<p style="color:red;">{!!$errors->first('profile')!!}</p>@endif
{!! Form::text('name') !!}
@if ($errors->has('name'))<p style="color:red;">{!!$errors->first('name')!!}</p>@endif
```

Or you can display all of them:

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div style="color:red;">
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <p>{{$error}}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Also you may not use `public function messages()` method and define all the messages for your language using `resources/lang/pt/validation.php` file.